# Push data from Java backend to jsp frontend

Tags: java, jsp, websocket

I currently have a 'stand-alone' java backend process pushing events / data into MySQL tables and a frontend jsp (Tomcat) polling (via a timer) the database to update a 'status display'. Polling is, of course, rather slow.

I want to be able to 'push' data directly from the backend to frontend but not by using any form of timed push.

Is this possible, by modifying the backend java and using HTML5 websockets (and HTTP POST), I read somewhere that websockets only works with a push from a webserver and cannot work with a 'separate' backend java application.

I know you can get MySQL to trigger messages on row updates but then the frontend still has to 'react' to those somehow and would probably be as slow as polling.

Thoughts appreciated.

Regards
Active

Comment: what you mean by 'seperate' application?

Comment: The java backend piece is a jar and runs as a stand-alone listener (listening for network evenets / data). The only 'common' connection (currently) between backend and frontend is the database.

Comment: Opening connection to 80 port isn't an option for you? I mean to listen network as a server rather plain java.

Comment: Opening  a connection to port 80 would make no difference (this would be the same as conventional websockets operation). If something happens at the backend I need the frontend to update instantly.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html

Comment: Thanks, yilmaz, though i think this is subject to the same limitations as stated in my post. The server in my case is a java process, not a web server. I will study further.

Comment: If your front is a Tomcat, maybe you can consider the JSF option. I'm not sure if it fits your architecture but you can try: your back-end fires some CDI event which are observed in your front-end. The observes "pushes" to the HTML pages via either JSF 2.3 websocekt (Java EE8) or [Ominifaces websocket](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2016/04/omnifaces-23-brings-jsf-and-websockets.html). It's the same thing. I'm linking to BalusC blog as OmniFaces showcase is currently down